# How to show the jpeg2k image in android

Tags: android

I'm getting the ImageIO compressed base64 string from the server. I'm trying to show the jpeg2K image in Android side. I tried with the ImageIo.read(inputstream);

Getting now **class not  found exception** in the run time .

Below check the below code.

```
byte[] output = com.secuera.ucms.encoders.Base64.decode(inputImage.getBytes());
        ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(output);        
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(in);
  Iterator<ImageWriter> writers = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("JPEG");
```

Getting the exception like below in run time

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.imageio.ImageIO
```

How can i solve this problem ?

Comment: please post your code and logcat error if any error